# Use phone interactively with TTS

Tags: accessibility, text-to-speech

I am speech impaired and trying to find a way to use my phone using TTS and have an active conversation without having to go through a 3rd-party.  There are plenty of apps for the TTS, but I have not been able to find one that I can incorporate into actually speaking (me texting) to a live person.

Currently, I am using the "TALK" app from Google Play Store just to use my phone and TTS and communicate with someone I am face-to-face with, but would like to do the same thing via phone.

If anyone knows of such an app or a way I can accomplish it with multiple apps, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really get it... You want to send the voice of TTS through a regular phone call, so that you can communicate with others away from you? Why is instant messaging not an option?

Comment: Hi Andy, IM works fine with friends and family and email works in some cases. but I need something for calls to other places, such as making a doctor appointment, or a business that does not have IM or email available to the public. Also it would help for when someone calls me and they are not aware of my speech impairment. I hope that clarifies it more.

Comment: Ah that, makes much sense. Upvoted for awareness.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called TTY (Teletypwriters) or RTT (Real-Time Text) and can be enabled directly via the [Phone by Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en_US&gl=US). The following instructions are for the default [Phone by Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en_US&gl=US), but may vary depending on your phone model, app, and carrier.

The instructions below are detailed on the Google Support pages for [Enabling RTT](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/9042284?hl=en) and [Change phone settings -> Use TTY or RTT with calls](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2895524#zippy=%2Cuse-tty-or-rtt-with-calls).

### Using RTT

- Turn on RTT in [Phone app settings](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2895524#zippy=%2Cuse-tty-or-rtt-with-calls)
- Dial a number or select a contact and tap `RTT` to place the RTT call
- After the other person answers, the text you enter is visible in real time as you type

### Using TTY

- Turn on TTY in [Phone app settings](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2895524#zippy=%2Cuse-tty-or-rtt-with-calls)

  - To hear and speak on the phone with no text support, tap TTY Off.
  - To use typed text in both directions, tap TTY Full.
  - To type text and hear the other person reply aloud, tap TTY HCO.
  - To speak aloud and read the other person's reply as text, tap TTY VCO.